# Docker Desktop cannot access web from container

Tags: windows, docker

Tried almost every attempt found here in the community but didn't figure out how to access web through continers created in my Docker Desktop Environment.

This is my last attempt with Ubuntu (also tried Centos and Debian suites):

```
docker run -i -t --rm=true ubuntu /bin/bash
root@310f7a660efd:/# apt-get update -y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.173). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.173). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.173). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.174). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.24). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.23). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.173). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If i ping google.com from the server no problem but just can't access repos. 
Seems a proxy problem but just because I set proxy in the Docker settings it allows me to download images from dockerhub.
Also tried DNS fixed to 8.8.8.8.
My OS is Windows 10 and this is Docker info:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 19.03.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894--------------16b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03----------9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.184-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.952GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: UL2M:2GDU:GGIH:IO6C:EJWA:YUXM:5DFL:F6Q4:XTFE:K3MN:7474:TY4J
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 38
  Goroutines: 58
  System Time: 2019-10-07T13:34:51.1886632Z
  EventsListeners: 1
 HTTP Proxy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:3128
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

This is quite sad situation since if a container can't access web it's very limited.

Also if I put unreachable path from those stack in my chrome they are perfectly available.

Hope for some advice to put me in the right direction.

Comment: Seems like some Network issue, maybe firewall, can you access the ubuntu repository from the host?

Comment: Yes if I put the repos in the browser I can access them.